# Is it ill advised to update Ubuntu on VirtualBox + Best Practices?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I am running on Windows 8.
I had Ubuntu 12.04 running as guest on VirtualBox 4.3.10 r93012 and once I updated it, it began booting into an empty black screen.

I reinstalled the guest additions but it didn't help.
This happened to me in the past on multiple occasions which I never learned from.

Is it just wrong to install Ubuntu's updates when running it as a guest OS on VirtualBox?

Or other some best practices (other than backing up the vdi of course)?

Comment: Is that Black screen appears while  restarting your host OS or guest OS?

Comment: Guest OS - I am running Windows 8 and Ubuntu is running as guest

Comment: It is possible I made a noob mistake and didn't install dkms before I installed guest additions. :)

Comment: post the above comment as an answer(elaborately)

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite: DKMS is not needed for installing guest additions. It will only help to automatically re-install GA after a  kernel update. Are you able to manually start lightdm from a TTY?

Comment: @AvinashRaj It does not really answer my q. It was just a conjecture about what caused the black screen.

Comment: @Takkat Sorry, I didn't really expect help with my specific problem. That vdi is already gone and I decided to install 14.04 instead. But thanks I will check that if it happens again. I was mostly asking for best practices and to know if this is a common issue or one that mysteriously haunts me personally. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with upgrading Ubuntu to a newer release from a Virtual Box installation. Before we proceed we may want to consider the following:

- A new installation may be faster than performing an upgrade.
- A dynamically growing disk file will considerably gain physically allocated space during a distribution upgrade (because of package cashing and reorganizing).
- A brand new distribution release may not yet be fully supported by Virtual Box.
- Best advice is to wait with a distribution upgrade until a new Virtual Box update had fixed possible issues.

The developers of Virtual Box do a tremendously helpful job in making this software compatible with almost any operating system. This however is a process needing considerable effort.

Therefore we can not expect that Virtual Box will be up-to-date exactly at the release point of any new Ubuntu release. At present Ubuntu 14.04 is not yet officially supported from the [Oracle Virtual Box download choices](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads). This usually will take some time. Until then we may likely still be able to run Virtual Box but it may need another update of the Virtual Box software until issues and bugs from integrating with a new distribution are being fixed.

Comment: Wait, as far as I understand, the download choices are for installing VirtualBox on an OS, not using VirtualBox to run the OS? Is that incorrect?